# How to know if there is any scheduled timers

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, awt

How to know if there is any scheduled [timers](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/javax/swing/Timer.html) currently?

There is [TimerQueue](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/javax/swing/TimerQueue.html) to manage a queue of Timers, but all stuff is private or package private.

Thanks.

Comment: Beware: TimerQueue _does not_ manage a queue of java.util.Timer, instead it manages a queue of javax.swing.Timer

Comment: curious: why do you think you need that info?

Comment: I would like to suspend test execution until there are any background sheduled tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is TimerQueue to manage a queue of Timers, but all stuff is private or package private.

Access modifiers don't stop [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). So you can do something like:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
TimerQueue tq = (TimerQueue) Timer.class.getField("queue").get(t);
boolean isEmpty = (Boolean) TimerQueue.class.getMethod("isEmpty").invoke(tq);
```

The member names were digged from JDK source code. Private stuff is not intended to be accessed this way, so this may break anytime. There's no robust way to do this. It's a pity that `Timer` doesn't provide such API.